# How to remove data in ToDoLis

Tags: reactjs

As you can see in the React code I am trying the remove single data in array but I am struggling to remove it. What I want to do if remove statement is a successfully deleted (it is actually I doing TODO List in that the removeElem function properly not working )

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const UseAraY = () => {
  const clearArray = () => {
    setmyArray([]);
  };
  const bioData = [
    {
      id: 0,
      myName: "vedu",
      age: 24,
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      myName: "eedu",
      age: 25,
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      myName: "ganu",
      age: 27,
    },
  ];

  const removeElem = (id) => {
    const NewArray = myArray.filter((Elem) => {
      return Elem.id !== id;
    });
    setmyArray(NewArray);
  };

  const [myArray, setmyArray] = useState(bioData);
  return (
    <>
      <p>I from UseAraY</p>
      {myArray.map((Ele) => {
        return (
          <h1 key={Ele.id}>
            My is Name: {Ele.myName} & My is age {Ele.age}
            <button onClick={() => removeElem(Ele.id)}>Remove</button>
          </h1>
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={clearArray}> clear</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default UseAraY;
```

Answer (score 0):

The id is not unique in the data. As you can see. id = 0 for each record.

Solution: Make is unique for each record.

```
const bioData = [
        {
            id:1,myName:'vedu',age:24
        },
        {
            id:2,myName:'eedu',age:25
        },
        {
            id:3,myName:'ganu',age:27
        }
    ]
```